How to create load modules from C code in IBM z/OS
I'm trying to compile load modules from C code on IBM z/OS using xlc compiler.
So far I have just shared object like library
xlc -c src/func1.c -o obj/func1.o
xlc -o lib/func1.o obj/func1.o
and I can compile my Cobol test running that function and it works
cob2 -v -o test test.cbl lib/func1.o
Could anybody explained me if this object is what is called load module ?
If not, is it possible to create load modules in unix shell with xlc compiler from C code and how ?

In z/OS Unix, the executables are normally generated as program objects (generally newer and better than load modules). To get a load module, you need to output the result to a PDS (partitioned dataset) and ensure that you are not using any program object required features (like using the GOFF object file format). You can output to a PDS by giving the output name to be a PDS. Ex. cob2 -o “//’my-pds-name(mymember)’” test.cbl lib/func1.o
Hope this helps,
z/OS XL C/C++ Compiler team

one minor point - program objects go in PDSE's (not PDS's). Old school load modules go into PDS's.

Please note you're better off fully qualifying the PDS. So, do something like '//MYUSER.LOADMODS(MYMEMBER)' rather than just '//((mymember')

Thank you.  Edited original answer . Did not notice the formatting ate a portion of the answer.

Thanks for all the tips. I wonder if it is possible ti generate load modules from C code and xlc compiler for further use with Cobol. I read that Cobol 4.2 was the last compiler with load modules.

I suppose a good question is why you want load modules instead of program objects...some people just use these terms interchangeably - be curious if there's a reason you actually need a load module. That aside, you can also just have a manual link-edit with the "ld" command - it takes all the ".o" files you create and can output a load module, shared library, program object - basically, any type of executable.
